# How to extract most used colors from image ? ( ColorThief / PIL is returning wrong values )

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I have example picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KXRg.jpg

Where the most used color is: **#f6f6f6** by far (98%)

**Using PIL:**

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open(000777.sk.jpg)
width, height = img.size
convert_rgb = img.convert('RGB')
colors = img.getcolors(width * height)
```

This will return as most used colors:
(389267, (255, 255, 255)), (346, (254, 255, 255)), (281, (252, 255, 255))... so #ffffff, #feffff, #fcffff... clearly wrong answer...

**Using ColorThief**

```
from colorthief import ColorThief
color_thief = ColorThief('000777.sk.jpg')
palette = color_thief.get_palette(color_count=10)
```

This will return (243, 243, 243), (52, 50, 50), (239, 131, 52), (148, 148, 148), (241, 114, 24), (210, 163, 133)]... which is #f3f3f3, #343232, #ef8334

Again not correct answer...

What is going on ?  Online color identifiers can get the answer right ( like https://labs.tineye.com/color/ will get perfect answer... )

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out... this is working for me:

```
def get_colors(pic):
    color_str = []
    img = Image.open(pic)
    width, height = img.size
    quantized = img.quantize(colors=10, kmeans=3)
    convert_rgb = quantized.convert('RGB')
    colors = convert_rgb.getcolors()  
    color_str = sorted(colors, reverse=True)
    final_list = []
    for i in color_str:
        final_list.append(i[1])
    return final
```

This will return correct colors in RGB sorted by most used to least

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through each pixel, add the pixel color to a hashmap (Dictionary) if it is not included yet, or if it is included, increase the counter.

```
color = some_color;
if color in my_map
    my_map["color"] = my_map["color"]+1
else
    my_map["color"] = 1
```

After that you can sort based on the map value, or loop to get the max value.

Comment: I thought that what getcolors function does... but it picks wrong colors or there is something else I'm not getting :(